# How to List SYNONYMS that no longer point to a valid object?

Tags: oracle, metadata, synonyms

I have a table (`OBJECTS_TO_UPDATE`) with several objects I need to update, some are `SYNONYMs` for objects that no longer exist.

I want to create a query to list them. But I am stuck.

My table `OBJECTS_TO_UPDATE` has these columns:

- `OBJECT_NAME`
- `OBJECT_TYPE`
- `OWNER`

In words what I want to do goes along these lines:

- I filter my `OBJECTS_TO_UPDATE` table by `OBJECT_TYPE = 'SYNONYM'`.
- Using the Owner and Name I can get the `SYNONYM` in `ALL_SYNONYMS`.
- Using the `TABLE_OWNER` and `TABLE_NAME` and search for it in the dba_objects, if the object doesn't exist, then the synonym is no longer valid.

I want to write a query using all those conditions but I am having issues.

```
select *
from OBJECTS_TO_UPDATE o2u 
where o2u.OBJECT_TYPE = 'SYNONYM' and NOT EXISTS ( 
                            --select * from dba_objects dobj
                            --where dobj.OWNER
                            select * from ALL_SYNONYMS syn
                            where  syn.OWNER = o2u.OWNER and syn.SYNONYM_NAME = o2u.OBJECT_NAME)
```

I am stuck/confused about what to do inside the `NOT EXISTS`.
How can I achieve what I need? I have DBA privs.

Also, is this the best way to achieve what I want? Maybe there are some other views I should use that more direct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't use the option suggested by BriteSponge because the value of the COLUMN Status in ALL_OBJECTS doesn't seem reliable.
I could find a SYNONYM that had status VALID but the object it was pointing to didn't exist.

The list of Objects I want to update is the OBJECTS_TO_UPDATE table.
I could list all the synonyms from the OBJECTS_TO_UPDATE table that were pointing to an object that no longer existed with the following query:

```
select *
from OBJECTS_TO_UPDATE o2u 
where o2u.OBJECT_TYPE = 'SYNONYM' and EXISTS ( 
                            select * from ALL_SYNONYMS syn
                            where  syn.OWNER = o2u.OWNER and syn.SYNONYM_NAME = O2U.OBJECT_NAME
                            and NOT EXISTS (
                            select * from dba_objects dobj
                            where dobj.OWNER = syn.TABLE_OWNER and dobj.OBJECT_TYPE != 'SYNONYM' and dobj.OBJECT_NAME = syn.TABLE_NAME
                            ))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can query the `ALL_OBJECTS` view for `object_type = 'SYNONYM'` and `status != 'VALID'`.
However all_objects status is set based on the status of the object that it is referring to. Synonyms, which aren't automatically invalidated if the underlying table disappears. So the `STATUS` column of `ALL_OBJECTS` is not reliable to use.

Try using this query:

```
SELECT obj.owner, obj.object_type, syn.synonym_name, tab.table_name
    FROM objects_to_update obj 
        INNER JOIN all_synonyms syn 
            ON obj.object_name = syn.synonym_name 
        INNER JOIN all_tables tab 
            ON  tab.table_name = syn.table_name 
            AND tab.owner = syn.table_owner 
    WHERE obj.object_type = 'SYNONYM' ;
```